# Is it possible to tell Yarn not to create a yarn.lock file?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, yarn-lock.json

With npm you can create a .npmrc file with "package-lock=false"
Is there something similar with Yarn?

Answer (score 4):

1. You can use this during yarn install

   ```
   yarn install --no-lockfile
   ```

It means yarn don’t read or generate a yarn.lock lockfile.

2. You can also use:

   ```
   yarn install --pure-lockfile
   ```

This means yarn don’t generate a yarn.lock lockfile.

3. You can also use:

   ```
   yarn install --frozen-lockfile
   ```

   Don’t generate a yarn.lock lockfile and fail if an update is needed.

Comment: Bummer, that's what I thought. Developers will have to explicitly say it when they install dependencies for my library. In contrast to `npm` where I can decide myself that it should never create a lock file for you.

Comment: Yarn 3 doesn't have the `--no-lockfile` option.